# Upgrading my Rally app from rally SDK 1.32 to rally SDK 2.0p5

Tags: javascript, rally

Please can anyone help me with this, how following Syntax's will be in Rally SDK 2
Or you can refer me some documentation for this, as I am unable to find any.

```
rally.function_name = function (rallyDataSource, config) {

var dataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                                                '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                                                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

chooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser(chooserConfig, dataSource);
```

How to define function as I was able to do it in rally SDK 1

```
    function getTypeFromRef(ref) {
        if (rally.sdk.util.Ref.isRef(ref)) {
            var list = ref.split("/");
            list.pop();
            return list.pop();
        }
        else {
            throw "Function getTypeFromRef expected a Rally Reference.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version is 2.0rc3 and the docs may be found here: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/

If you are using an old on-prem instance of Rally and 2.0p5 is the latest version you have access to the docs for that are here: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/

It's unclear from your code above what exactly you are trying to do.  Hopefully the docs can help you get started.  Or, update your post with a more specific question/code example once you get a little farther along.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have seen above documentation. Can you please refer me documentation link for old SDK 1.please